# Usage of flatMap() in Java8

Tags: java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I have an `Artist` class as follows:

```
class Artist {
    private final String name;
    private final String origin;
    private Stream<Artist> members;

    public Artist(String name, String origin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.members = null;
    }

    public Artist(String name, String origin,Stream<Artist> members) {
            this.name = name;
            this.origin = origin;
            this.members = members;
    }

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public Stream<Artist> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Now we create a list of artists, where the name of the artist is a band or a single entity. For single entity `"members"`attribute remains null.Now the list is as follows :

```
List<Artist> artists = Arrays.asList(
                new Artist("Fossils","Kolkata", Stream.of(new Artist("Rupam Islam","Kolkata"), new Artist("Deep","Kolkata"),new Artist("Allan","Kolkata"), new Artist("Chandramouli","Kolkata"),new Artist("Tanmoy","Kolkata"))),
                new Artist("Linkin Park","California",Stream.of(new Artist("Chester Bennington","California"),new Artist("Dave Farrell","California"), new Artist("Mike Shinoda","California"),new Artist("Rob Bourdon","California"),new Artist("Brad Delson","California"))),
                new Artist("Cactus","Kolkata",Stream.of(new Artist("Sidhartha Sankar","Kolkata"),new Artist("Dibyendu Mukherjee","Kolkata"), new Artist("Ritaprabha","Kolkata"),new Artist("Sudipto","Kolkata"),new Artist("Mainak","Kolkata"))),
                new Artist("Backstreet Boys","Florida",Stream.of(new Artist("A. J. McLean","Florida"),new Artist("Howie D.","Florida"),new Artist("Nick Carter","Florida"), new Artist("Kevin Richardson","Florida"), new Artist("Brian Littrell","Florida"))),
                new Artist("Prohori","Kolkata",Stream.of(new Artist("Pritam","Kolkata"))));
```

We want to have no of single entity from "Kolkata". Using external iteration we can have following solution:

```
int totalMembers = 0;
for (Artist artist : artists) {
    if(artist.getOrigin().equals("Kolkata") {
        Stream<Artist> members = artist.getMembers();
        totalMembers += members.count();
    }
}
```

What will be the solution for internal iteration using `stream()` and `flatMap()` with the help of Lambda-Expression ?

I have thought of a solution but may be it is incorrect.

```
int totalMember = artists.stream()
                         .filter(d -> d.getOrigin().equals("Kolkata"))
                         .flatMap(e -> e.getMembers())
                         .map(f -> 1).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

Comment: Big thing why is it incorrect is you have a field of type `Stream<Atrist>`. Streams can be used only once, if you call your code two times in a row you'll get an exception. Other than that, your solution can be improved by using appropriate builtins (like counting collector), but overall is fine.

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar a bit unclear.. you want the total number of artists from a certain region where `members` is null? Taking your example: `new Artist("Fossils", "Kolkata",
                        Stream.of(new Artist("Rupam Islam", "Kolkata"), new Artist("Deep", "Kolkata"), new Artist("Allan", "Kolkata"),
                                new Artist("Chandramouli", "Kolkata"), new Artist("Tanmoy", "Kolkata")))`. Should this produce zero or 5? You want to count the inner Artists also?

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar your example of `external iteration` (besides the possibility of throwing a NullPointerException because members might be null), also does not fulfill your own requirements : `We want to have no of single entity`, where `For single entity "members"attribute remains null`.

Comment: @Eugene I want to count only the inner artist, count will not be taken place in case of "Bands" (i..e artists having members)

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar got it. Seems like my first solution from the answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: But your first solution is giving the result 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your external loop counts the number of members that have the band coming from `Kolkata`. if you actually want that:

```
long result = artists.stream().filter(a -> a.getOrigin().equals("Kolkata"))
            .filter(a -> a.getMembers() != null)
            .flatMap(a -> a.getMembers())
            .count();
```

Comment: Your first solution is giving the result 0

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar for your example what is the desire output 11? If so then the second example counts those inner members

Comment: That solution gives me an error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar run `just` the second, without the first. You have  Streams - you can act on them only once.

Comment: What a mess I had made .. I was running both internal and external iteration at the same time.. that is why it was throwing an error.. Thanks a lot

Comment: or `.filter(a -> a.getMembers() != null) .mapToLong(a -> a.getMembers().size()) .sum()`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will give the expected output i.e **11**. You also can use :

```
int totalMembers = (int) artists.stream()
                                .flatMap(d->d.getMembers())
                                .filter(d->d.getOrigin().equals("Kolkata"))
                                .count();
```

Difference between both the solutions is I have `flattened` the list before `filtering` it and used `long count();` instead of `reduce()`.
What later solution does is, it checks the `origin` from `Stream<Artist> members` and not the `origin` of `artists`. Hope this help.
I would appreciate if someone can discuss the optimized solution.

Comment: Your Solution gives an error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Comment: Don't know why is it giving IllegalStateException to you, because it seems to be working fine for me. Can you please copy-paste the code and then try.

Comment: My bad.. It's working fine. But we need to use the filter() first. It will reduce some of the overhead as we filtered out the "bands"

Comment: Using filter before flattening the list may skip the members of `Kolkata` that are in the bands of other `origin`.
`new Artist("Agnee","Delhi",Stream.of(new Artist("Roy","Kolkata");`
So, in above case Roy want be included in the count.

Comment: In this case, you are getting `IllegalStateException`, because you are using a stream twice. Unlike List, you can use stream only once, once a stream is evaporated, using it again gives you `IllegalStateException`.

Answer (score 0):

Sum the counts of the streams in an `LongStream`:

```
long totalMember = artists.stream()
                          .filter(d -> d.getOrigin().equals("Kolkata"))
                          .map(Artist::getMembers)
                          .filter(m -> m != null)
                          .mapToInt(Stream::count)
                          .sum();
```

Comment: `For single entity "members"attribute remains null`. It seems like there should be another filter at least.

Comment: @eugene OK... added not null filter

Comment: I am not sure what the OP actually wants to count.. He says `We want to have no of single entity from "Kolkata"`, but his external loop counts the actual members (the way you have done it).

Comment: also, I don't think this will compile.. Stream::count returns a long and sum() too

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution too. It may also happen that a band member form a band of particular locality may not be from the same locality. So the exact solution will be :

```
long totalMember = artists.stream().filter(a -> a.getOrigin().equals("Kolkata"))
                            .flatMap(a -> a.getMembers())
                            .filter(a -> a.getOrigin().equals("Kolkata"))
                            .count();
```